# Electron app error (im not very good with node.js)

Tags: node.js, json, electron

Working on an electron project (im not very good with node.js) and am getting this same parsing error every time I run. I'm not sure how to fix it because this is my first time using electron for html.

````
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'start'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.1.0
2 info using node@v17.0.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Administrator\electron-quick-start\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Administrator\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 11ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 11ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
21 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 1ms
22 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 4ms
23 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 3ms
24 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
25 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 1ms
26 timing npm:load Completed in 23ms
27 timing command:run-script Completed in 6ms
28 timing command:start Completed in 13ms
29 verbose stack JSONParseError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 238 while parsing '{
29 verbose stack   "name": "uswl",
29 verbose stack   "version": "1.0.0"'
29 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json-fast\index.js:11:61
29 verbose stack     at async RunScript.run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:87:19)
30 verbose cwd C:\Users\Administrator\electron-quick-start
31 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
32 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
33 verbose node v17.0.0
34 verbose npm  v8.1.0
35 error code EJSONPARSE
36 error path C:\Users\Administrator\electron-quick-start/package.json
37 error JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 238 while parsing '{
37 error JSON.parse   "name": "uswl",
37 error JSON.parse   "version": "1.0.0"'
38 error JSON.parse Failed to parse JSON data.
38 error JSON.parse Note: package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
39 verbose exit 1```
````

Comment: Looks like a formatting problem with your `package.json`, please post that as well.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.